How can I get the name of the user that approved azure devops pipeline
How can I get the name of the user that approved the deployment and echo the information into a script step?
Here's how I've setup azure devops pipeline yml with approval requirement:

set up an environment and define the user that can approve it
have the following stage in my yml

    stages:
    - stage: authorise_deployment`
      jobs:
      - deployment: deploy
        environment: env
        strategy:
        runOnce:
         deploy:
          steps:
            - task: Bash@3
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: echo 'Name of approver'


Below is a sample (requiring two persons approvals )
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - "master"
  paths:
    include:
    - "azure-pipelines.yml"

jobs:
  # Track deployments on the environment.
- deployment: wbApprovalTest
  displayName: wb approval test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist.
  environment: 'test'
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self 
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'check approvals'
          env:
            SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: |
              $headers = @{
                  Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
              }

              $uri = "{0}/{1}/_apis/pipelines/approvals?`$expand=steps&api-version=7.1-preview.1" -f $env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI, $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID

              Write-Host "uri concat is $uri"

              Write-Host "build id is $($env:BUILD_BUILDID)"

              $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Get' -Headers $headers

              foreach($item in $response.value){
                if($item.pipeline.owner.id -eq $env:BUILD_BUILDID){
                    foreach($item2 in $item.steps){
                        Write-Host "who approve the pipeline --- $($item2.actualApprover.uniqueName)"
                    }
                    break
                }
              }

result:


You can use the REST API "Approvals - Query" to get the users who approved the deployment in current pipeline.
# azure-pipelines.yml

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - deployment: deploy
    environment: myEnv
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'Who Approved'
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                organization="myOrg"
                project="myProj"
                uri="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?\$expand=steps&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                response=$(curl -X GET -u :$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN $uri)
                actualApprovers=$(echo $response | jq '.value[] | select(.pipeline.owner.id==$(Build.BuildId))' | jq -r '.steps[].actualApprover.displayName')
                echo "-----------------------------------------------"
                echo "The following users approved this deployment:"
                echo "$actualApprovers"


If you assigned multiple approvers and also set "At least 1 approver must approve" on the Approval, above method will return the display name of the approvers who approved. For the approvers who did not approve, it will return 'null'.



Was hoping to have a built in system varaible but the code suggest does work
